# Storing and retrieving temporary mp4 files

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, temporary-directory

I am capturing a five seconds long mp4 file. I would for the User to be able to play and review the video before uploading it to Parse. I don't want to save the video to the local photo library, I just want to replay. Should I be saving the file to the temporary directory like so:

```
    NSString *outputPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];
    NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:outputPath];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputPath])
    {
        NSError *error;
        if ([fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputPath error:&error] == NO){
            NSLog(@"File removed from outputPath");
        };
    }

    [MovieFileOutput startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputPath]
                                  recordingDelegate:self];
```

Can I play the video using this method?

```
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Output.mp4"];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
self.avPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:fileURL];

AVPlayerLayer *movieLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];
self.avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[_avPlayer play];
```

}

Comment: The first line should be: `NSString *outputPath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"output.mov"];`.

Comment: And if `removeItemAtPath:error:` returns `NO`, it means the file was not removed.

Comment: "*Can I play the video using this method?*" Why don't you try it and see? Use more specific terminology when describing your problem. If it *doesn't work*, indicate that.

Comment: I have tried it but I don't see the video. I'm wondering if this is the correct way to retrieve a file from them temp directory.

Comment: It should work if you use the same filename in both parts of the code. `output.mov` is not the same as `Output.mp4`.

Comment: Good point. I missed that completely.